# PHPUnit provider not working with dependencies

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit 3.4.9, but I'm having some problems with the `@depends` annotation.  It works like in the examples, but breaks when the producer reliers on a provider.  I don't know if this is meant to work or not, but my code is basically in the form:

```
<?php
    class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
      /**
       * @dataProvider provider
       */
      public function testEmpty ($data)
      {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertTrue(empty($stack));

        return $stack;
      }

      /**
       * @depends testEmpty
       */
      public function testPush (array $stack)
      {
        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertFalse(empty($stack));

        return $stack;
      }

      /**
       * @depends testPush
       */
      public function testPop (array $stack)
      {
        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertTrue(empty($stack));
      }

      public function provider ()
      {
        return array(
           // Some testing data here...
        );
      }
    }
```

The code above is just an example, but shows what my code's structure is like.  When ran, it skips the consumer tests, acting as though the producer had failed.  I'm expecting that for every set of testing data in the provider, the producer will be run with that data, and all of its consumer correspondingly run.

Comment: From the PHPUnit manual: "When a test depends on a test that uses data providers, the depending test will be executed when the test it depends upon is successful for at least one data set. The result of a test that uses data providers cannot be injected into a depending test."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question is already 2 days old i give it a shot:

It doesn't seem to work the way you want it to.

`@depends` just looks if a test with the name provided has run and gets the result. It doesn't even know or care about the @annotations of said test.

I'd guess (haven't dug deep enough into the phpunit source to be 100% sure) tests with `@depends` are run as "group of tests" internally and not as a single one so there is not test named "testEmpty" and the depends fails.

So to provide a workaround the only thing i can think of right now is to call those "sub tests" directly.

```
<?php
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  /**
   * @dataProvider provider
   */
  public function testEmpty($data) {
    $stack = array();
    $this->assertTrue(empty($stack));
    $this->nextTestOrJustAllInOneTestcaseSaidly($stack);
    return $stack;
  }

  protected function nextTestOrJustAllInOneTestcaseSaidly($data) { ... }
```

Hope that helps or at least motivates someone else to answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  A little while after posting I worked around it just by combining all the tests into one test, but I was mostly curious if this was expected behavior or not.  I'll take yours as the answer either way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with a test that depends on another test (and more specifically data returned by that test) which uses a data provider.

I overcame the problem by setting the value (which I would of normally simply returned from the dependent test) as a static variable, which I was then able to access in my other tests later.

```
<?php
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected static $foo;

    public function provider() { ... }

    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testOne( $data ) {
        self::$foo = array();
        $this->assertTrue( empty( self::$foo ) );
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo() { 
        $this->assertTrue( empty( self::$foo ) );
    }
```

Still hacky, but slightly less than perhaps calling the next test function from within another test.

Answer (score 0):

If a test has a data provider, then all data provided will be fed into this test. Only then the next test is run, which might depend on the first test to succeed. What is NOT done is that all data provided to the first test is also fed to the second.

`@dataProvider` takes priority over `@depends`. A test can depend on another test that completely testes all of its data provided, but it won't get this data for itself. To get such a thing you really have to combine all dependant tests into one function.

On the other hand, such a test setup might be non-obvious in the first place, but tests should be easy to understand. Consider refactoring the tests.